# Splash screen doesn't come full screen when loading windows App tablet

Tags: windows, tablet-pc

I am working an app for windows tablet so I want to put some image on splash screen.I have different images according to different sizes that shown in windows app.After that setting the image in splash screen it shows only center of the page.Here I have attached also.

Hope someone help me[image]

Comment: What does your corresponding code look like? What did you try?

Comment: I just want to show splash screen in full page when the app starts.help me to get the issue